# How to draw lines connecting points in python?

Tags: python

I would like to draw something like this in Python.

[image]

I tried in matplotlib but I wasn't sure where to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can plot Bezier curves between points like in the example [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/shapes_and_collections/quad_bezier.html).  Using that example, you can do:

```py
import matplotlib.path as mpath
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


points = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]  # point on x-axis
ypos = [0 for _ in points]  # positions on y-axis (all zero)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 2))

# plot points
ax.plot(
    points,
    ypos,
    marker="o",  # use circular marker
    mfc="k",  # set the marker face colour to black ("k")
    mec="k",  # set the marker edge colour to black
    ms=6,  # set the marker size to 6
    ls="none",  # turn off lines between points
)

# add labels
for i in range(len(points)):
    ax.text(
        points[i],
        ypos[i] - 0.2,
        f"{points[i]}",
        horizontalalignment="center",
        verticalalignment="top",
        fontfamily="serif",
    )

# specify which points to join
join = [
    [[1, 3], 1],  # join points 1 and 3 with a curve of height 1
    [[3, 8], 2],  # join points 3 and 8 with a curve of height 2
    [[5, 7], 1],  # join points 5 and 7 with a curve of height 1
]

# draw curves
Path = mpath.Path
for j in join:
    pp = mpatches.PathPatch(
        Path(
            [
                (j[0][0], 0),  # start point of curve
                (j[0][0] + (j[0][1] - j[0][0]) / 2, j[1]),  # mid-point of curve (halfway between points on x-axis)
                (j[0][1], 0)  # end point of curve
             ],
             [Path.MOVETO, Path.CURVE3, Path.CURVE3]
        ),
        fc="none", transform=ax.transData
    )
    ax.add_patch(pp)

ax.axis("equal")

fig.patch.set_visible(False)
ax.axis("off")
```

which produces:

[image]

You could add more points to the Bezier curves to alter their shape a bit, e.g., switching to four points defining the curves with:

```
for j in join:
    pp = mpatches.PathPatch(
        Path([(j[0][0], 0), (j[0][0] + (j[0][1] - j[0][0]) / 8, j[1]), (j[0][0] + 7 * (j[0][1] - j[0][0]) / 8, j[1]), (j[0][1], 0)],
             [Path.MOVETO, Path.CURVE4, Path.CURVE4, Path.CURVE4]),
        fc="none", transform=ax.transData
    )
    ax.add_patch(pp)
```

gives:

[image]

which is closer to your original plot in the question.

Comment: You could also look at the [`annotate`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.annotate) method, which has various connection styles that can be controlled to some degree https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/userdemo/connectionstyle_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-userdemo-connectionstyle-demo-py.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [Graphviz python package](https://pypi.org/project/graphviz/) is a better fit for this problem:

https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#neato-no-op-flag

> The neato layout engine supports an additional rendering flag that allows more control over the node positioning and the edge layout via the pos, overlap, and splines attributes.
>
> Use the neato_no_op keyword argument of render() or pipe() to pass it to the layout command:
>
> ```
> doctest_mark_exe()
>
> import graphviz
>
> n = graphviz.Digraph(name='splines', engine='neato',
>                     graph_attr={'splines': 'true'},
>                     node_attr={'shape': 'point'})
> n.node('a', pos='0,0!', color='blue')
> n.node('b', pos='100,0!', color='green')
> n.node('c', pos='50,50!', color='red')
> n.edge('a', 'b', pos='0,0 30,66 70,60 100,0')
> n.render(neato_no_op=2, directory='doctest-output').replace('\\', '/')
> ```

The magic here are the graph and node attributes which style the graph with points and splines. I don't think explicit position should be necessary, if you set `rankdir` attribute of the graph to "LR".

More documentation for the attributes is available in the [graphviz documentation](https://www.graphviz.org/).